# Find longest (string) key in dictionary

Tags: python

This question is similar to [Python - Find longest (most words) key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321160/python-find-longest-most-words-key-in-dictionary) - but I need the pure number of characters.

Example input:

```
d = {'group 1': 1, 'group 1000': 0}
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: "to build a table"? Please explain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternative, which is as fast as @jamylak's solution and more pythonic:

```
from itertools import imap
max(imap(len, d))
```

See comparison:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "d = {'group 1': 1, 'group 1000': 0}" "len(max(d,key=len))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.538 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "d = {'group 1': 1, 'group 1000': 0}" "max(len(x) for x in d)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.7 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "d = {'group 1': 1, 'group 1000': 0}; from itertools import imap" \
  "max(imap(len, d))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.557 usec per loop
```

Comment: +1 I agree this way is the way to go. Note for python 3 users: `map` is `imap` in Python 3.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to find the documentation for imap in itertools. Is this information outdated?

Comment: @beruic `imap` has been renamed `map` and is a built-in in python3.  You can simply use `max(map(len, d))`

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> max(len(x) for x in d)
```

or

```
>>> max(map(len, d))
```

Comment: @jamylak - and both are slower for your two-elements-dictionary than your solution…

Comment: @jamylak Your solution is faster, though.

Comment: @eumiro Alright then I will leave it here it but this is the better answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> d = {'group 1': 1, 'group 1000': 0}
>>> len(max(d, key=len))
10
```

This solution is the fastest but I prefer the solutions by @eumiro and @ms4py since they do not repeat the `len` function twice and are more pythonic imo.