# Getting the top length of a key in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, string-length

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find longest (string) key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895567/find-longest-string-key-in-dictionary)

Without folding. Example:

```
from functools import reduce
dict = {'t1': 'test1', 'test2': 't2'}
print(len(reduce(lambda x, y: x if len(x) >= len(y) else y, dict.keys())))
```

Is there any way to get the longest key's length in a a dictionary (preferably in one line)? There's nothing wrong with folding but I'm just interested if there's another way to do it in Python 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do

```
max(map(len, my_dict))
```

This will take the lengths of all keys and extract the maximum of these lengths.

To get the longest key itself, use

```
max(my_dict, key=len)
```

Comment: is there any way to get only keys that are 3 letters in length?